# Javascript window.setTimeout precision

Tags: javascript, settimeout, timing

I have recently started exploring Javascript in more detail, and how it executes within the browser. Specifically, the setTimeout function.

My understanding is that calling `setTimeout(foo,x)`
will pass a handle to foo to be executed after x milliseconds. How reliable is this timing? Obviously if another long-running script is still executing after x milliseconds then the browser won't be able to call foo, but can I be absolutely certain that `setTimeout(foo,101)` will always be executed after `setTimeout(foo,100)`?

Comment: No, you can't be absolutely certain of anything, and javascript timers aren't very accurate either, but most of the time they are accurate enough, and will execute the function close enough to the set time.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `setTimeout(foo,x)` will execute `foo` *no sooner than_ x **milliseconds*** later. MDN document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

Comment: As you know  JavaScript work like a Single thread execution,so it will wait in a Que  for their turn to execute,but You an be sure the given timeout is minimum time.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the timeout is in miliseconds, therefor 1 sec = 1000 ms. consider that.
you can always be sure that delay of 1001 will be later than 1000.
**BUT** You must remember that if the 2nd methods relay on changes of the first method it doesnt mean it will work good.
the first methods can take for reasonable time of 3ms (not a complicated one) and the 2nd one can start only 1 ms after the first one causing your reliability on the first method to fail.
i would suggest not to use this feature but in some rare cases.

you can tag me in this answer comment for your specific case and i can suggest the right way to work it out.

Comment: Edited the original post to reflect milliseconds rather than seconds. From what you're saying it sounds like if the first call to foo takes longer than 1 second, the second call to foo will begin executing before the first call has finished? Or do you mean the second call will begin executed 1ms after the first call returns? My understanding was that the execution was single-threaded, so it couldn't start the second call if the first was blocking it.

Comment: javascript is sychro language. basically function wont start before the others finishes. this is why timeout is is needed in very rare cases. but, the use of Global variables is dangerous, as I was saying about parameters reliability and as you were saying, java script is a single-threaded language, methods cannot be called in the same time.

Answer (score 2):

In nodejs we may be able to time events very precisely by setting a timeout to expire *shortly before* the desired moment, and then creating a tight series of event-loop ticks, and after each one checking how close to the target time we've approached:

1. Imagine `Date.now()` is currently, e.g., 11000 (unrealistic; just an example!)
2. Determine we want to act in EXACTLY 4000ms
3. Note that means EXACTLY when `Date.now() === 15000`
4. Use setTimeout to wait less than 4000ms, e.g., 3800ms
5. Keep awaiting microticks until `Date.now() >= 15000`

   - This won't block the event loop
   - (But it will keep your CPU very busy)

```js
let preciseWaitMs = async (ms, { nowFn=Date.now, stopShortMs=200, epsilonMs=0 }={}) => {
  
  let target = nowFn() + ms;
  
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms - stopShortMs));
  
  // Allow `epsilonMs` to shift our wait time by a small amount
  target += epsilonMs;
  
  // Await a huge series of microticks
  // Note: this will eat cpu! Don't set `stopShortMs` too high!
  while (target > nowFn()) await Promise.resolve();
  
};

(async () => {
  
  let t1 = Date.now();
  let target = t1 + 2000;
  console.log(`Trying to act in EXACTLY 2000ms; at that point the time should be ${target}`);
  
  await preciseWaitMs(2000);
  
  let t2 = Date.now();
  console.log(`Done waiting; time is ${t2}; deviation from target: ${t2 - target}ms (negative means early)`);
  
})();
```

Note that `preciseWaitMs(4000)` will never wait *less* than 4000ms. This means that, if anything, it is biased towards waiting too long. I added an `epsilonMs` option to allow the bias to be moved back according to the user; for example `preciseWaitMs(4000, { epsilonMs: -1 })` may cancel out `preciseWaitMs`'s bias towards always being late.

Note that some js environments provide a higher-precision current-time query than `Date.now` - for example, nodejs has `require('perf_hooks').performance.now`. You can supply a function like this using the `nowFn` option:

```
{ epsilonMs: -0.01, nowFn: require('perf_hooks').performance.now };
```

Many browsers support `window.performance.now`; try supplying:

```
{ epsilonMs: -0.01, nowFn: window.performance.now };
```

These settings achieve sub-millisecond "precise" timing; off by only about 0.01ms on average

Note the `-0.01` value for `epsilonMs` is what seemed to work best for my conditions. Note that supplying fractional `epsilonMs` values is only meaningful if `nowFn` provides hi-res timestamps (which isn't, for example, the case with `Date.now`).

Note that in some environments (e.g. browsers), `setTimeout` reliability is completely at the mercy of events outside the programmers control. For example many browsers will prevent timers events from executing until their tab is focussed. This can always lead to arbitrary inaccuracy for any `setTimeout`-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers use single thread for UI and JavaScript, which is blocked by synchronous calls. So, JavaScript execution blocks the rendering.

> Events are processed asynchronously with the exception of DOM events.

but `setTimeout(function(),1000)` trick is very useful. It allows to:

> Let the browser render current changes. Evade the “script is running too long” warning. 
>   Change the execution flow. Opera is special in many places when it comes to timeouts and threading.

So if another function is executing it will handle it by running in parallel.

another thing to `setTimeout(function(),1000)` her time is in millisecond not in seconds.